# Advent of code 2023 day 2: count possible qube games - in pure Bash

Tags: programming-challenge, bash

To paraphrase the [puzzle](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/2), Santa takes a walk with an Elf, and they play a game involving a bag of colorful cubes. In each game, there is an unknown number of each colored cubes in the bag, and the Elf pulls out a number of cubes, for example:

> ```
> Game 1: 3 blue, 4 red; 1 red, 2 green, 6 blue; 2 green
> Game 2: 1 blue, 2 green; 3 green, 4 blue, 1 red; 1 green, 1 blue
> Game 3: 8 green, 6 blue, 20 red; 5 blue, 4 red, 13 green; 5 green, 1 red
> Game 4: 1 green, 3 red, 6 blue; 3 green, 6 red; 3 green, 15 blue, 14 red
> Game 5: 6 red, 1 blue, 3 green; 2 blue, 1 red, 2 green
> ```

#### Part 1

In part 1, we want to know which games would have been possible if the bag contained only 12 red cubes, 13 green cubes, and 14 blue cubes. The answer is the sum of the eligible game ids, in the above example 1 + 2 + 5 = 8.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Solver for https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/2 part 1
# Redirect the input file to this script, for example day2part1.sh < path/to/input.txt
#

set -euo pipefail

max_red=12
max_green=13
max_blue=14

is_eligible_cubes() {
  local count color
  count=$1
  color=$2

  case $color in
    red) ((max_red < count)) && return 1 ;;
    green) ((max_green < count)) && return 1 ;;
    blue) ((max_blue < count)) && return 1 ;;
  esac

  return 0
}

is_eligible_game() {
  local iterations count color
  iterations=$1

  while [ "$iterations" ]; do
    [[ $iterations =~ ([0-9]+)\ (red|green|blue) ]] || break
    count=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    color=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    iterations=${iterations:${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}}
    iterations=${iterations#*[,;]}
    is_eligible_cubes "$count" "$color" || return 1
  done

  return 0
}

solve_day2_part1() {
  local sum game_id iterations
  sum=0

  while read _ game_id iterations; do
    game_id=${game_id%:}
    is_eligible_game "$iterations" && ((sum += game_id))
  done

  echo "$sum"
}

solve_day2_part1
```

#### Part 2

To paraphrase the change in part 2, for each game, we're looking for the maximum number of cubes per color that were drawn, multiply them together, and then sum this number for all games. With the example above this would be 48 + 12 + 1560 + 630 + 36 = 2286.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Solver for https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/2 part 2
# Redirect the input file to this script, for example day2part2.sh < path/to/input.txt
#

set -euo pipefail

solve_day2_part2() {
  local sum game_id iterations count color red green blue
  sum=0

  while read _ game_id iterations; do
    game_id=${game_id%:}
    red=0
    green=0
    blue=0

    while [ "$iterations" ]; do
      [[ $iterations =~ ([0-9]+)\ (red|green|blue) ]] || break
      count=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
      color=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
      iterations=${iterations:${#BASH_REMATCH[0]}}
      iterations=${iterations#*[,;]}
      case $color in
        red) ((red < count)) && red=$count ;;
        green) ((green < count)) && green=$count ;;
        blue) ((blue < count)) && blue=$count ;;
      esac
    done

    ((sum += red * green * blue))

  done

  echo "$sum"
}

solve_day2_part2
```

#### Review request

What would you do differently?

Answer (score 5):

It's going to be a really minor thing, but a review is a review and thus doesn't belong in the comments.

I've learned that calling files `solve_day2_part2` in an "AdventOfCode2023" folder is perfectly fine. Calling the *function* `solve_day2_part2`, completely destroys the possibility for re-use. Ever. There's not even a year mentioned in the function itself, so the function name isn't guaranteed to be unique in your codebase.

The following line is for the file, not the function:

```
# Solver for https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/2 part 2
```

And thus does not really tell us what the function does. There could be lots of functions in that file and you could've copied a 2018 solution into your file for all we know.

For a one-off hobby project, the damage is minimal. But this code shouldn't pass a professional review. Considering you can fix that by using a better function name... I'd say it's worth considering.

Answer (score 4):

> What would you do differently?

Well, choosing a language better suited to the task springs to mind, maybe python.

In particular, I find this inconsistency distracting when reading such scripts:

```
      [[ $iterations =~ ...(red|green|blue) ]] || break
      ...
    ((sum += red * green * blue))
```

We have the usual `$` dollar sigil for variable interpolation.
And then we switch to an entirely different language
which eschews that sigil.
And the identifiers are perfect, wouldn't change them,
yet we have this jarring disconnect between RGB literals above
then RGB variables below.
Coding up arithmetic in bash asks the Author to attend
to too many details, like whether the cost of forking
off a child to evaluate an expression is "mandatory" (e.g. `sort`, `wc`)
or "too much" as we see here.

---

## part 1

I like your shebang, quite flexible.
The `set` is conservative, very nice.

I confess I found the `is_eligible_cubes` predicate
a bit confusing, but that's because `0` denotes success,
so we kind of see the boolean sense flipped.
IDK, maybe assign `FAIL = 1` and return that?
What you wrote is just fine.

In a similar vein, I had some trouble
seeing why we wouldn't want `max_red <= count`.
I find it more natural to mention the variable `count`
before the constant `max_red` that we're comparing against.
Somehow I find I more rapidly parse `count <= max_red`
than the equivalent `count > max_red` or `max_red < count`.
I think it's because the real number line is conventionally
depicted left-to-right, and I'm focused on the small (finite)
"good" region while ignoring the infinite set of "bad" counts
that disappears off into the distance toward the right.

At the call site further down it looks beautiful,
very intuitive.

```
  while read _ game_id iterations; do
```

Sorry, I'm not getting why you chose an identifier of `iterations`.
That's not a term from the business domain.
The problem statement suggests that some form of "subsets of cubes"
would lead to a more descriptive identifier.

---

## part 2

No notes (beyond what I mentioned above).

Looks great, very clear.

Comment: *"Well, choosing a language better suited to the task springs to mind, maybe python."* << I disagree. After doing a few of these tasks, one should easily be convinced that it makes much more sense to choose "a language I want to improve with" or "a language I find fun", rather than "a language that is best-suited for this task".

Comment: @Stef Agreed, it's not uncommon to do such challenges in languages you either know nothing about or want to push to its limits.

Comment: As someone who does a lot of shell programming for the past 25 years and counting, I'd highlight that on many systems (embedded, constrained by security paperwork, ancient, etc.) some, hopefully POSIX-compatible, shell interpreter is the only one you have (and often not bash, but some ksh or busybox derivative). A Python or Perl or PHP footprint may be larger than the whole storage in such box or SBC or boot-handling environment. So being proficient with shells (and being open to use of dumb syntax and maybe monkey-patch it with better code if you detect a more capable interpreters) is useful.

Comment: Coming to think of it, many such scripts can be made for distributability - as systems automation or build recipes, etc. and you don't know about capabilities of the target system it ends up on. Availability of a baseline shell is something you can almost count on, and that you have a chance to write it so that it would behave similarly for some three decades worth of distros and platforms.

Comment: In the 1980's the "dual universe" Pyramid osx and Sequent dynix/ptx offered charming differences in how shell + basic utilities behaved, sometimes favoring USG sysV features and bugs, sometimes favoring Berkeley ones. So I tended to conservatively stick to just least-common-denominator in scripts, suffering `[` and `expr` forking costs, and would switch to a more expressive language once the script had installed what's needed. // As far as a small footprint requirement goes, eLua / [Squirrel](http://squirrel-lang.org) seems more popular than TinyScheme, Forth, or tcl.

Comment: Re naming "iterations", I actively wanted to use a term from the domain (the problem description), but I couldn't find one. "games" was my first thought, but that term was already overloaded. Given a bag of cubes, we repeatedly take out a bunch of cubes, put them back, draw again, so I thought a single instance of taking cubes could be considered an "interation", and as a single line represents multiple of these, I named that plural. I don't like it either, I still can't think of a better term.

Comment: Hmmm, I sympathize, though the quoted "game" doesn't sound too bad. We draw a batch of cubes from an urn, make an observation, and replace them. So maybe a "draw"? Or a "sample"?

Comment: @Stef: I think the "better suited language" part of this answer is an insightful discussion about exactly what kinds of downsides you can or do run into when using bash for this sort of problem.  And perhaps something to think about in terms of choosing variable names that aren't identical to literal strings you're parsing for or printing, to mitigate this. 
 I don't think this answer is saying that it wasn't a good learning exercise, just that for production use you'd prefer a different language if it was an option.